# Programmatically Setting Style From App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I created a new Calendar control in code:

```
  Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
```

I'd like to set its CalendarDayButtonStyle with a style that's defined in my app.xaml

```
  calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle = ...
```

But I don't know how to do this. Also I don't have access to "FindResource" which is what I've seen other people use. (I'm inside an ICommand so I don't have access to this method) are there any other ways?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Application.Current.FindResource`.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty straight forward...

Instantiate a ResourceDictionary in your Application

#### App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/AssemplyOfResource;Component/Resource.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Retrieve your style in code

#### CodeBehind

```
  object resource = Application.Current.FindResource("KeyName");
  if (resource != null && resource.GetType() == typeof(Style))
      calendar.Style = (Style)resource;
```

Most people you'll see just use Application.Current.FindResource("KeyName") and cast it which is fine except when the graphic designer decides to mess with the ResourceDictionaries. This will cause the application to not crash.

If you need some specific Calandar example visit:

[MSDN Magazine Customizing the New WPF Calendar Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx)